# Multi joined MySQL query has an issue

Tags: mysql

I have the following query, the job scenario is:

I have three tables. Categories, Roles and Roles_to_categories table.

roles_to_categories table:

```
--id--   --role_id-- --category_id--
```

A role in roles table, may be bound to several categories in a pivot table named `roles_to_categories`. I want a role, for instance `admin` to fetch all the categories from the table `categories` which are bound to it in table `roles_to_categories`.

It works fine, but the problem is when aggregation comes in: `GROUP_CONCAT()`.
I want to just get the list of parent categories, and include their children in a separate column by using `GROUP_CONCAT()`. My problem is that `GROUP_CONCAT()` seems to ignore the roles_to_categories pivot table when it retrieves the list of children, which means it includes the children of the a certain category that is NOT ALLOWED (I mean there is no record in `roles_to_categories` to bind it a role)

The query is:

```
select categories.name as cat_name, categories.id as cat_id, 
roles.name as role_name, roles.id as role_id, roles_to_categories.id as cat_id, roles_to_categories.role_id as role_id,
roles_to_categories.category_id,
group_concat('name: ', categories2.name) as cat_children
FROM roles left join roles_to_categories on roles.id = roles_to_categories.role_id
left join categories on roles_to_categories.category_id = categories.id 
left join categories as categories2 on categories2.parent_id = categories.id
WHERE roles.name = "admin";
```

It selects required columns from all three tables, starting from `roles` then it `left joins` to `roles_to_categories` to get its related records and then re-`left-joins` on categories table from `roles_to_categories` to select categories whose ids exists in the fetched records and ....

Comment: You'll need to `group by` the non-aggregated columns (i.e. everything in the select except `group_concat`)

Comment: Can you elaborate on it? As an answer. thanks

Answer (score 1):

`group_concat` is an aggregate - you'll need to group by all non-aggregated columns in your select list.

You've also included multiple aliases of both sides of joined columns in your query - this will be confusing and redundant, and aliased `category.id` and `roles_to_category.id` to `cat_id`.

In this case, since you want to concatenate all children of a parent category, this will be like so:

```
select 
  categories.name as cat_name, categories.id as cat_id, 
  roles.name as role_name, roles.id as role_id,
  roles_to_categories.id as roles_to_cat_id,
  group_concat('name: ', categories2.name) as cat_children
FROM 
  roles left join roles_to_categories 
   on roles.id = roles_to_categories.role_id
   left join categories on roles_to_categories.category_id = categories.id 
   left join categories as categories2 on categories2.parent_id = categories.id
WHERE 
  roles.name = 'admin'
GROUP BY 
  categories.name, categories.id, roles.name, roles.id, roles_to_categories.id;
```

Comment: Sorry it seems you did not get my question. It still includes the illegal child in the column `cat_children`.

Comment: I'm not quite following. The graph will only recurse one level deep of sub categories (did you want recursive depth?). It doesn't appear to make a difference whether the `group_concat` is pre-generated in a derived table and joined to. [SqlFiddles](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/609aa/2)

Comment: It would be better if it be recursive, though currently it is not. My problem is quite solved by re-left-joining to a similar query...